# Loop through objects React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

My React Component has the following render

```
componentWillMount () {
    var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hart88/198f29ec5114a3ec3460/raw'
    Request.get(url)
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({cakes: data.text});
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.cakes} //prints this ok

            {
              this.state.cakes.map(cake =>{ // error here
                return <p>{cake.title}</p>;
              })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

i am trying to loop through this.state.cakes which is an array of objects.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Update - an abbreviated example of `this.state.cakes`:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Lemon cheesecake",
        "desc": "A cheesecake made of lemon",
        "image":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3.mediafileserver.co.uk/carnation/WebFiles/RecipeImages/lemoncheesecake_lg.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title":"Banana cake",
        "desc":"Donkey kongs favourite", 
         "image":"http://ukcdn.ar-cdn.com/recipes/xlarge/ff22df7f-dbcd-4a09-81f7-9c1d8395d936.jpg"
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can you please print what's in the `Cakes` array ? Because if it's array of objects (which seems most obvious here). Then the error is in ` {this.state.cakes}` line not the other one.

Comment: @MinkeshJain  updated the {this.state.cakes},

Comment: How are you loading the data into state? Is it using a `fetch` from a server. `map` is undefined because `cakes` isn't an array yet which means that the data is not available for use by the component.

Comment: @Spdexter - how is `state.cakes` defined in your component constructor? Is the example that you provided hard-coded, or as @Andy suggests, it's the result of a fetch?

Comment: @Andy  Added the code of full Component - it is a result of a fetch, that i use to setState

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the state is set as the resutl of a fetch you might not be able to access the data immediately due to the async operation. You can catch this by inspecting the state and if it has no length return a message or a spinner component to indicate the data's on its way.

Once `state.cakes` is updated with the data from the fetch operation the component will re-render.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { cakes: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/cakes')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(cakes => this.setState({ cakes }));
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.cakes.length) return <Spinner />
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.cakes.map(cake => {
        return <p>{cake.title}</p>;
      })};
    </div>
  )
}
```

As the others have mentioned it's also good practice to add [`key`s](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to your iterated elements.

Comment: Thanks ! i understood what u said and applied. i now get LOADING for a few secs and then get this error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.cakes.map is not a function :(

Comment: Add the code for your fetch operation either to your question or a jsfiddle and i'll take a look.

Comment: @Spdexter, I've added some example fetch code. Does yours look similar to that?

Comment: this is my componentWillMount () {
  var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hart88/198f29ec5114a3ec3460/raw'
  Request.get(url)
  .then(data => {

   this.setState({cakes: data.text});
  })


 }

Comment: Sorry updated my question with componentWillMount() where i fetch

Comment: 1) Where are you parsing the JSON (see my updated answer) 2) If you are parsing the data try `...cakes => {this.setState({ cakes }); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151844/discussion-between-spdexter-and-andy).

Comment: I was unable to get .json() working with Superagent for some reason, replaced with Fetch and it's working great- thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you've used curly braces (understandably) where React actually requires parentheses. Since you're getting the data from a `fetch`, be sure to set your constructor with a preliminary `cakes` object as well.  Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        cakes: []
    }
}

render() {
    if (this.state.cakes.length > 0){
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.cakes.map(cake => (
                        return <p>{cake.title}</p>;
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

    return null
}
```

The issue is that the component is rendering and you're telling it to do something with an array called `this.state.cakes`, but `this.state.cakes` hasn't been defined yet because the `fetch` hasn't returned yet. Setting your constructor like this passes an empty array to the `render` so it doesn't freak out, and then when your data loads and your state updates, it will re-render with your data.

The reason `{this.state.cakes}` was, on its own, rendering just fine is because for the first split second of the component's existence, that value was `undefined`, which means that React basically just ignored it - once the data loaded, it rendered. However, the `map` method failed because you cannot pass an undefined array into `map`.

And as Ha Ja suggested, you should probably add a `key` attribute to the `<p>` elements.

Comment: Hi thanks @skwidbreth, it didnt work-the error i get is Cannot read property 'map' of undefined!

Comment: `cakes` isn't an array (yet). Add the rest of the component code @Spdexter, so we can see how your state is populated with your JSON.

Comment: Er, how can you get a result from printing `this.state.cakes` but then have `cakes` as `undefined` in the next line of code. Are you sure `cakes` is an array?

Comment: How have you defined `state.cakes` in your constructor?

Comment: Hi @skwidbreth  i really appreciate it! i have updated constructor and also incuded keys but i get TypeError: this.state.cakes.map is not a function error - i checked for any typos but none

Comment: Ah yeah, you'll want to conditionally render that - see my updated answer.

Comment: @skwidbreth thanks for edit and your help. when i first fetch data from that url i get a response and assign response.text as result - do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
{this.state.cakes.map((cake, i) => <p key={i}>{cake.title}</p>;)}
```

Do not forget to add the `key` attribute. 
Ps: It would be better to use an unique Id instead of the array index. SO if you have an id for each array item, better write:

```
{this.state.cakes.map(cake => <p key={cake.id}>{cake.title}</p>;)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed brackets inside of your `map`

```
    {this.state.cakes.map(cake =>{ // errors here
        return <p> {cake.title} </p>;
    })}
```